# npgsql connection pooling with two connection strings specifying same host

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, connection-pooling, npgsql

If I have two different `DbContext`s whose connection strings differ only in the `Database` field but `Host`, `Username`, `Password`, etc. are all the same will the same connection be reused when using both `DbContext`s in the same thread? From looking at the pgadmin dashboard this seems to be the case but I don't see it documented anywhere.

Additionally, I have some test code that I expect to *not* work as it is using two different `DbContext`s in EF Core 6 within a `TransactionScope` and AFAIK EF Core 6 does not support distributed transactions at all. However, the code *does* work and does not throw any exceptions.

This is using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL version 6.0.7

Answer (score 0):

In version 7.0, Npgsql introduced support for DbDataSource ([release notes](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/7.0.html#dbdatasource)). When using this new feature, a DbDataSource corresponds to a connection pool, and so instantiating and using two data sources would mean two completely separate pools.

However, when using the more traditional mode where a connection string is provided directly (no NpgsqlDataSource), the pool is managed internally inside Npgsql, and is keyed by the connection string. So in that case, using the same connection string means using the same connection pool. To separate pools, you can vary the strings e.g. by introducing an `Application Name` parameter - but overall it's recommended to switch to NpgsqlDataSource.